# Install IJulia offline

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia

I would like to install IJulia from a non-connected computer. However, the command Pkg.add("IJulia") seems to require a connection. Is there a way to download manually the package and then specify a local path for the install?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be a problem for all the Julia packages you want to install, not only IJulia. Julia packages work by cloning stuff into `~/.julia/v0.4` and `~/.julia/v0.4/.caches` (for julia 0.4 at least) you will need to grab all the things and put them in the right place yourself.

Something else you can do is to use the `insteadOf` option of git so that `Pkg` believe it is pulling things from github, when you actually have a local clone of the repository.

You can find some information on installing packages (and configuring `insteadOf` for git) in  [this section](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/packages/#packages) of the julia manual.

Comment: Thank you ; I'll have a look. If there are only a few files, it might be worth the sweat, I'll have to find the list of the files.
It would be great to have a global package like anaconda.

Comment: for IJulia, I doubt there will be "only" a few file, you have to build ZMQ if not present which is quite a alot. Also if you don't have IPython already installed it will pull all the IPython dependencies.

Comment: Hum, I can't make it work. I thought downloading the related packages would be enough (I downloaded 3 depending on the displayed errors), but with no success. I guess at my level it is not possible. I hope some solution will be released later (something like IPython).

Comment: You probably need to issue a `julia>Pkg.build()` after `$echo 'IJulia' >> ~/.julia/REQUIRE`